# Can a child instance access dynamic parent instance attributes and attribute values?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

So I have a parent and child class:

```
class Map(object):
    def __init__(self, name=''):
        self.mapName = name
        self.rules = {}

class Rule(Map):
    def __init__(self, number):
        Map.__init__(self)
        self.number = number

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Map " + self.mapName + " rule number " + str(self.number)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  map = Map("thismap")
  rule = Rule(1)
  map.rules[rule.number] = rule
```

with the above:

```
$ python -i inherit.py
>>> map
<__main__.Map object at 0xb7e889ec>
>>> map.rules
{1: Map  rule number 1}
>>> map.rules[1]
Map  rule number 1
>>>
```

I have tried adding:

```
  map.rules[2] = Rule(2)
```

but that still gets:

```
$ python -i inherit.py
>>> map.rules
{1: Map  rule number 1, 2: Map  rule number 2}
>>>
```

and:

```
 map.rule = Rule(3)
```

which also doesn't really get me what I'm looking for:

```
>>> map.rules
{1: Map  rule number 1, 2: Map  rule number 2}
>>> map.rule
Map  rule number 3
>>>
```

What I'm trying to do is link a child instance to an instance of a parent class and access dynamic parent class attributes and values, which in this case would be handy because I'd like to populate a map with a list of rules and print the rules including the parent map name for each rule.  I'm just not sure how I would go about doing this in python.  Or I'm just trying to use inheritance in a way it wasn't meant to be used, or missing something tragically obvious.

Any thoughts are welcome, and thanks in advance

Comment: `self.mapName` is not set by the constructor of your subclass, so it has the default value, which is the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing inheritance. Rule doesn't need to inherit from Map to access a Map's attributes, and attaching a Rule to a Map won't make it see the Map's attribute values as its own. Inheriting from Map means a Rule **is** a Map, not that it's linked to or managed by a Map.

If you want a Rule to know about its Map, have it record which Map it's associated with:

```
class Rule(object):
    def __init__(self, number, map):
        super(Rule, self).__init__()
        self.number = number
        self.map = map
    def __str__(self):
        # __str__, not __repr__, because __repr__ should be unambiguous,
        # have a clear beginning and ending, and obviously indicate the type.
        return "Map {} rule number {}".format(self.map.mapName, self.number)

Rule(1, map)  # makes a rule associated with map
```

You'll probably want to fold generating a rule and adding it to a map into one operation - probably an instance method of `Map`.